# Android: Memory leaks because of activity and context stored as objects attributes?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-context, android-memory

Is there any risk to raise a "Memory leaks" exception (*e.g.*) if we create an object attribute `activity` and another one `context`, defined in the `onAttach()` method?

It can be useful, especially for `context` in a dialog class.

Comment: Its generally a bad idea to have Context or Activity as a member variable/attribute. Use Inversion of control as you can. The worst case wrap the context in a WeakReference to prevent memory leak if it exists as an edge case.

Comment: What is "inversion of control"? i didn't understand your last sentence?

Comment: Look up inversion of control online. But in short, is the ability to pass context to a module as a method parameter and the module will decide what they want to do with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the reference to `#onAttach()`, it sounds like you're dealing with fragments.  As per Android [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments#CommunicatingWithActivity):

> the fragment can access the FragmentActivity instance with getActivity() and easily perform tasks such as find a view in the activity layout

The APIs are designed to expose any needed `Context` to you so it's more idiomatic to simply use `getActivity()` where/when necessary.

In general if you take a reference to any UI element, or any type of `Context` you must make sure that either:

1. The lifetime of where you're holding a reference is contained completely within the lifetype of the thing being referred to
2. OR ... a `WeakReference` is used and checked for `null` before use in order to allow the referred-to item to get garbage-collected

The lifecycle of UI elements are strictly contained within the enclosing `Context`, so it is normal for them to directly reference the context without use of a `WeakReference`.

Furthermore, there are explicit examples of relying on the parent context outliving the fragment *[specifically for dialogs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html)*.